# Using memcpy to clone an entire region of memory into my own

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, anti-cheat

I need to make a copy of a region in memory (specifically 00401000-00E88000) and then clone it to my allocated space with memcpy. Is there any way to do this with C++ efficiently inside of a DLL? Heres my current code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LPVOID base = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 0xFFFFFF, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

int main()
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    //for later
    getchar();
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        main();
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can copy memory using `memcpy`. Yes, `memcpy` is efficient. What is the question here?

Comment: The question is how do I copy a whole region of memory @user2079303

Comment: And the answer is `memcpy( dest, src, size );`.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: When we ask you to post code, you're supposed to post the relevant code. This code has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is divided in pages, so in that range you might have unallocated space; first you have to map the memory using [VirtualQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then you can copy all data with memcpy.

In any case, if you are in the same address space of the target, you can just use the memory as if it was yours depending on what you want to do with it. (It looks like you are trying to dump that memory block, if that is the case you can write the memory directly to a file without having to actually copy it first)

Also,